# RuntimeException in MediaRecorder.start()

Tags: android, runtimeexception, android-mediarecorder

I have a RuntimeException when I call the method "start()" on my MediaRecorder object. I can not paste the stack trace because I have discovered the bug on Google Analytics.
This is the code:

```
    MediaPlayer p = new MediaPlayer();
    final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    final String path = getOutputAudioFilePath(activity);
    if (path == null)
        return;
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    recorder.setMaxDuration(300000);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    recorder.start();
```

Comment: put `recorder.start();`  inside your try-block. I guess it is not a good idea to start recorder if it is not prepared.

Comment: Do you have the following permission on your Manifest.xml?    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: @donfuxx I think you're right. I'm an idiot.

Comment: @joao2fast4u I already have this permission.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and it's all right. It works. But I used

```
final String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/myFile"
```

instead.

So make sure your getOutputAudioFilePath(activity) method is returning a valid path and a path that does not require manifest permissions you haven't added, cause it might lead to the exception you are getting.